# Magento - update cart item by item ID

Tags: php, magento

How to update cart item using item ID ? I have searched a lot but could not success, here is my codes -

```
require_once '../app/Mage.php';
Mage::app('default');

$qty = $_REQUEST['quantity'];
$item_id = (int) $_REQUEST['item_id'];
$cart = Mage::getSingleton('checkout/cart');
$quoteItem = $cart->getQuote()->getItemById($item_id);

/*$quoteItem = Mage::getModel('sales/quote_item')->getCollection()
   ->addFieldToFilter('item_id', array('in' => array($item_id)));*/
print_r($quoteItem);
if (!$quoteItem) {
    Mage::throwException('Quote item is not found.');
}

if ($qty == 0) {
    $cart->removeItem($id);
} else {
    $quoteItem->setQty($qty)->save();
}
$cart->save();
```

I am implementing it in API , however same code is working fine in website.Please help!!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I used the below code to update cart items and I am using observer to do that. can you please try this.

```
    $quote = $observer->getEvent()->getQuote();
    var_dump($quote->getId());

    $quote = Mage::getSingleton('checkout/session')->getQuote();
    //var_dump($quote->getId());
    $cartItems = $quote->getAllItems();
    //$storeId = Mage::app()->getStore()->getId();
    foreach ($cartItems as $item) {
        //echo $item->getSku();
        $item->set__($value); // desired quote field from database
        $item->save();
    }
    $quote->save();
```

Comment: I am using codes in web service , are you sure "session" work here ?

Comment: Fatal error: Call to a member function getEvent() on a non-object in /home/yxyshareoflovest/public_html/web-services/test.php on line 13

Comment: @SachinVairagi  remove below lines.

$quote = $observer->getEvent()->getQuote();
var_dump($quote->getId());

it works only in observer.

Comment: I am creating web service , it will be used in Android/iOS , so  Mage::getSingleton('checkout/session')->getQuote(); this will not work , can we load it with quote ID or customer ID ?

Comment: Yes, it wont work we you are using it for API. 
In that case you need to fetch quote info based on customer_id and quote update attribute. 


$collection = Mage::getModel('sales/quote')->getCollection();
$collection->addFieldToFilter('customer_id', $customer_id);
$collection->addFieldToFilter('store_id', $store_id);
$collection->addOrder('updated_at');
$quote = $collection->getFirstItem();

Comment: @JunaidFarooqui The above question and my answer is for Magento 1. Its not for Magento 2